# MVC3 uploadify Jquery plugin error HTTP 404 and IO error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, file-upload

I am using Uploadify v3.1 for MVC3 C#.

My cshtml code is

```
<div class="container_24">
    <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />
</div>
```

My js code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'method': 'post',
        'swf': '../../Scripts/uploadify-v3.1/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader': 'DashBoard/UploadFile'
    });
});
```

And the controller code is

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            // Verify that the user selected a file
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // extract only the fielname
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
            // redirect back to the index action to show the form once again
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

Now when i click the upload button it show two errors, sometime it **show IO error** and sometime it show **HTTP 404** error for some file. what is wrong ? help me please ?

Comment: Use the Asp.net MVC helpers to generate the paths: `'swf': '@(Url.Content("~/Scripts/uploadify-v3.1/uploadify.swf"))',
        'uploader': '@(Url.Action("DashBoard", "UploadFile"))'`. You can additionally setup an [onUploadError](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/onuploaderror/) to find out more about the cause of the error.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but your idea is not working :( what should i don now ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What size files are you uploading? Everything over 1MB or anything under?

Also what *sort* of 404 are you getting? If it's a 404.13 (file size error) then you're having the same problem I had. Good news. Because I fixed my problem. :)

If you're not sure what type the 404 is (Firebug will tell you), check your Windows event log and look in the "Application" log for a warning that looks like this:

- Event code: 3004
- Event message: Post size exceeded allowed limits.

If you've got both of these, then the problem is that IIS (which I'm assuming you're using) is not set up to allow big enough content requests.

Firstly, put this in your web config:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- maxAllowedContentLength = bytes -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="100000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Then this, in "system.web":

```
<!-- maxRequestLength = kilobytes. this value should be smaller than maxAllowedContentLength for the sake of error capture -->    
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="153600" executionTimeout="900" />
```

Please pay attention to the notes provided - maxAllowedContentLength is in **BYTES** and maxRequestLength in **KILOBYTES** - big difference.

The maxAllowedContentLength value I provided will let you up load anything upto around 95MB.

This solved my version of this problem anyway.

Comment: I'm having same issue as described by OP and this solution does not resolve my problem, is there any other way to fix the issue?